# permute() function in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix

I am trying to create a 2×961 matrix in MATLAB.

I use `meshgrid()` to create two 31×31 matrices, and then I use `cat()` to make a 31×31×2 matrix. I want to use `reshape()` to get the 2×961, but I need to rearrange the matrices using `permute()`...I don't totally understand how.

I know that MATLAB will try to arrange them by columns, one matrix then the other if I don't, but I don't know the specifics of how to use permute to avoid this.

---

```
[theta1, theta2] = meshgrid(linspace(-3*pi/4, 3*pi/4,31),...
                            linspace(0,2*pi,31));
grid = cat(3,theta1,theta2);
%something here using permute()
reshape(grid, [2 961]);
```

---

Ok, so now I have this

```
[theta1, theta2] = meshgrid(linspace(-3*pi/4,3*pi/4,31), linspace(0,2*pi,31));
grid = cat(3, theta1, theta2);
grid = permute(grid, [3 2 1]);
grid = reshape(grid, [2,961]);
x = torus_phi(grid);
surf(x, 'FaceAlpha', 0.75)
```

---

But, when I run it I get this weird looking graph, is there a way to get it clearer and one color.
I ultimately will need to have multiple surfs on the plot so I need to get the single color thing working.

Comment: Use a sample data to showcase the expected output?

Comment: I take it `out = [theta1(:) theta2(:)].';` is not what you want?

Comment: So, `reshape(permute(grid, [3 1 2]), 2, [])`?

Comment: My main goal is to understand how to use permute to accomplish this, I have read the descriptions of the function but I don't understand how it works, and I know that there is a way to use permute() to do this. So, I am really looking for some sort of confirmation about this, and a good explanation on how the order vector works here. If that makes it more clear. Thank you